# Google Cloud Speech API gives UNAVAILABLE: Channel in TRANSIENT_FAILURE state in Android

Tags: android, voice-recognition, speech-to-text, android-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I have been using [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/) for a while. I am specifically following [Google Speech Demo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech) provided by google. It is working with very great efficiency in devices with version 5.0 and higher.

But when I run it in Android version lower than 5.0, then it always gives me

> UNAVAILABLE: Channel in TRANSIENT_FAILURE state

I have searched it and found some [canonical error codes for Google APIs](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1beta1/Code), which specifies,

> **UNAVAILABLE**    The service is currently unavailable. This is most likely
>   a transient condition, which can be corrected by retrying with a
>   backoff.
>
> See the guidelines above for deciding between FAILED_PRECONDITION,
>   ABORTED, and UNAVAILABLE.
>
> HTTP Mapping: 503 Service Unavailable

So does that mean that Cloud Speech Services are not supported for Android devices lower than Android 5.0 ? Is there any workaround this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked through the Android example and couldn't see anywhere they are setting:

```
ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(mContext);
```

You can [read about it here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html#example_sync).

If that solves the problem, you may have more to come, as [I posted here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-speech-discuss/OFJ-oqY8Zeg) a few days ago.

Comment: Ok. This works for me. I will look out for https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-speech-discuss/OFJ-oqY8Zeg and see if I can find any solution. Meanwhile please do update, if you can get any success in that. Thanks a lot for a heads up !!

Comment: Glad that worked. I hadn't actually seen they'd uploaded an Android example and it's a little different to the Java adaptation I was using. I'll post back if I have any joy.